# How to call a python file that returns a list from another python file?

Tags: python

```
**File1**
`#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import ConfigParser
import re


def main(argv):
    pFilepath = "/tmp/system.conf"
    values=[]
    if not os.path.isfile(pFilepath):
        print("File path {} does not exist. Exiting...".format(pFilepath))
        sys.exit()  
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read(pFilepath)
    for i in range(len(sys.argv)-1):    
        parts=re.split('[:]',sys.argv[i+1])
        try:
            values.append(config.get(parts[0], parts[1]))
            #print (config.get(parts[0], parts[1]))
        except:
            print parts[1],' is not present in ',parts[0]

    return values


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    print main(sys.argv[1:])`
```

I have to run a python file1 which returns a list from another python file2. Is it possible to store the list that returned from file1 in file2 ?
From file 2 i have to run file 1.
File 1 returns list.
I have to get that list and store it in a list in second file.

**File2**

```
`#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import ConfigParser
import subprocess
import re
import string


def main():
    pFilepath = "/tmp/system.conf"
    values=[]
    if not os.path.isfile(pFilepath):
        print("File path {} does not exist. Exiting...".format(pFilepath))
        sys.exit()  
    vals = subprocess.call('python ./utility.py Environment_P1:name Environment_P2:id', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    #proc=pipe.communicate()[0]
    #vals=re.split('[,]',proc)
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        vals[i]=string.replace(vals[i],'[','')
        vals[i]=string.replace(vals[i],']','')
        vals[i]=string.replace(vals[i],"'",'')
        vals[i]=string.strip(vals[i])
        print vals[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   main()`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show your code please

Comment: I think I understood what you were going for in my answer. But as @BearBrown said. Please show us your code so we can help you find an answer to your question.

Comment: Reading the code, I don't think it will help. Please rephrase your question and explain what you are trying to achieve, in plain logic/ point form.  And when describe a program, call it a program , don't call it a file.   You will confuse yourself and everyone if you need to describe the program has a need to save data to another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can import file1.py into file2.py. The example below shows two ways you can return a list between .py files. You can return the list from a function or you can access variables in `file2` because you `import File1.py` into it.

File1:

```
#file1.py
def get_list():
    return [1,2,3,4]

lst=[5,6,7,8]
```

File2:

```
#file2.py
import file1
print(file1.get_list())
print(file1.lst)
```